# Table $ 2n-1 $ from $ n=2 $ to $ 50 $ except when $ n=3m-1 $

Tags: list-manipulation

How to `Table` $ 2n-1 $ for $ n $ from $ 2 $ to $ 50 $, except when $ n=3m-1 $ for another integer $ m $?

Answer (score 7):

Using [`Drop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop.html), [`Riffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html) and [`Complement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html):

```
Drop[Range[5, 2 50 - 1, 2], {3, -1, 3} ]
```

> {5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 
>   55, 59, 61, 65, 67, 71, 73, 77, 79, 83, 85, 89, 91, 95, 97}

```
Riffle[#, # + 2] &[2 Range[3, 50, 3] - 1]
```

> same result

```
2 Complement[#, #[[;; ;; 3]]] & @ Range[2, 50] - 1;
```

> same result

All three are faster than `Pick`+ `Unitize` combination from Henrik's answer:

```
nmax = 1000000;

e0 = Drop[Range[5, 2 nmax - 1, 2], {3, -1, 3} ]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> 0.0102131

```
e1 = Riffle[#, # + 2] &[2 Range[3, nmax, 3] - 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.0126898

```
e2 = 2 Complement[#, #[[;; ;; 3]]] & @ Range[2, nmax] - 1; //  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.0354908

versus Henrik's

```
d = Pick[2 # - 1, Unitize[Mod[#, 3] - 2], 1] &@Range[2, nmax]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.0526116

and chyanog's method:

```
(k = Floor[(2 nmax + 1)/3] - 1; 
 res = Range[4, 3 k + 1, 3] + BitAnd[Range[k], 1];) // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.0125891

```
e0 == e1 == e2 == d == res
```

> True

Comment: Very clever! +1

Answer (score 5):

The condition to avoid can be rewritten using Mod, hence:

```
Table[If[Mod[n, 3] != 2, 2 n - 1, Nothing], {n, 2, 50}]
```

Or you can use Map /@ instead of Table:

```
If[Mod[#, 3] != 2, 2 # - 1, Nothing] & /@ Range[2, 50]
```

(Thanks to Lukas Lang for the easier use of Nothing).

Comment: You could also return [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) in the else case to remove the unwanted elements directly

Answer (score 4):

An idiomatic way with `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
Reap[
  Do[If[Mod[n, 3] != 2, Sow[2 n - 1]], {n, 2, 50}]
  ][[2, 1]]
```

> {5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53,
>   55, 59, 61, 65, 67, 71, 73, 77, 79, 83, 85, 89, 91, 95, 97}

A harder to read, vectorized way: First create the list and pick the valid elements with `Pick`.

```
Pick[2 # - 1, Unitize[Mod[#, 3] - 2], 1] &@Range[2, 50]
```

> {5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53,
>   55, 59, 61, 65, 67, 71, 73, 77, 79, 83, 85, 89, 91, 95, 97}

The vectorized version is about 40 times faster:

```
nmax = 1000000;
a = Reap[Do[If[Mod[n, 3] != 2, Sow[2 n - 1]], {n, 2, nmax}]][[2, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = Table[If[Mod[n, 3] != 2, 2 n - 1, Nothing], {n, 2, nmax}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
c = If[Mod[#, 3] != 2, 2 # - 1, Nothing] & /@ Range[2, nmax]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
d = Pick[2 # - 1, Unitize[Mod[#, 3] - 2], 1] &@Range[2, nmax]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b == c == d
```

> 0.943828
>
> 0.907419
>
> 1.34615
>
> 0.018833
>
> True

Answer (score 2):

More efficient way

```
Clear["f*"];
f1[m_] := Module[{r = Range[4, 2 m - Mod[m, 3], 3]}, r[[1 ;; ;; 2]] += 1; r];
f2[m_] := Drop[Range[5, 2 m - 1, 2], {3, -1, 3}];

r1 = f1[10^7]; // RepeatedTiming
r2 = f2[10^7]; // RepeatedTiming

r1 == r2
```

> {0.11, Null}
>
> {0.14, Null}
>
> True